Is the phrase "until the 5th July" correct?
I received this text from my counsellor,
"I will not be available the 4th of July due to a family event. You will still be able to message me but I may not reply until the 5th July."
I think until the 5th July is a typo, and it should be until the 5th of July.
Is my thinking correct?

Note, there is regional variation in talking about dates. U.S. usually says the month first ("July 5th") and even writes it that way in digits (07/05/2024), while most of the rest of the world says the day before the month. Note that the U.S. independence day holiday is also known by the phrase "Fourth of July," as an exception to this pattern.

@AndyBonner: I think OP is asking about whether of is necessary, not the month/day sequence. Personally I wouldn't care whether it was present or not - same with the definite article before the ordinal, they're both effectively (and independently) optional.

@FumbleFingers Yes; my comment is tangential but I thought it was worth warning.

@FumbleFingers counsellor included "of" for July 4th, but for 5th July, counsellor did not. Isn't that weird?

Some (pedants?) may think so, but personally I think it's quite natural to drop unnecessary elements from repeated constructions. It's much the same as dropping back to Simple Past in a sentence that started with Past Perfect, or to Simple Present in a sentence that started with Present Perfect. If the extra complexity is optional, you might reasonably pay "lip service" to pedantry once, and thereafter just switch to "simplest is best".

5 April, April 5, April 5th, 5th April - all equally acceptable.

It's totally correct in both British and American English, based on Cambridge you can use phrases like:

Today is the 7th September.

Also more examples can be found on Grammarly and Wall Street English.
But still, based on EditorsManual, usage of such phrases is considered informal:

In British English, ordinals are sometimes used in dates, although
cardinal numbers are preferred in formal writing. Example:
Informal: On 1st April 1957, the BBC broadcast pictures of a spaghetti harvest in Italy.
Formal: On 1 April 1957, the BBC broadcast pictures of a spaghetti harvest in Italy.


This would be wrong in American English, which I would imagine is the origin of the OP's sentence given the reference to the 4th of July.

I'll include a notice, thanks @NuclearHoagie

@NuclearHoagie: I haven't checked, but my gut feel is it's actually more common in AmE than BrE to omit preposition of in such contexts. But both forms are common, and I certainly reject any claim that one is "wrong".

@FumbleFingers I don't think I've ever heard a native American English speaker drop the "of" and refer to a "4th July party". I've maybe seen it a handful of times in headlinese, but it is certainly not common.

...here's the last 50 years, showing that with / without of are now equally common in AmE, whereas 2 centuries ago of was far more common.

I found plenty of both forms doing some site-specific searches on The Washington Post.

@FumbleFingers Take a closer look at the ngram hits - many of the "10th August" hits are pulling bibliography citations, date lists, foreign newspapers, or are quoting historical diaries from non-Americans. I see hardly any usages of it in full grammatical sentences. "10th of August" on the other hand, returns almost nothing but full grammatical sentences.

@NuclearHoagie: I fully accept your point that "many" of the hits could be classed as "false positives". But even if only 1 in 10 or less prepositionless instances occur in what would otherwise be called full grammatical sentences, I think it's common enough that calling it "wrong" is pedantic.

@FumbleFingers I find that 1 in 10 to be a huge overestimate. I checked the first 100 ngram hits for "10th August", and there isn't a single one that's found in a full grammatical sentence by an American author.

@NuclearHoagie: I'd better concede then! It doesn't bother me, but if the "terse" form is that uncommon, I shouldn't label the preference for the more common form as "pedantry".

Yes, officially you are right and your thinking is correct. The phrase "until the 5th July" is grammatically incorrect and should be either "until the 5th of July" or "the July 5th". Well, you can expect the unnatural language even from native speakers.

"officially"? I don't recognize any concept of "authority" here.
